# Как можно ускорить код возврата медианы двух отсортированных массивов?

Tags: c#, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Задача с leetcode. Текст задачи:

> Учитывая два отсортированных массива nums1 и nums2 размера m и n соответственно, вернуть медиану двух отсортированных массивов. Общая сложность времени выполнения должна быть O(log (m+n)).

Саму задачу я решил уже, но хочу добиться максимально быстрого решения. На данный момент достиг максимально возможного для себя `160 ms` и `39.2 MB`. Как можно код сделать оптимальнее по скорости и потребления памяти?

```
public class Solution
{
    public double FindMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2)
    {
        nums1 = Concat(nums1, nums2);
        SortArray(nums1, 0, nums1.Length - 1);
  
        if (nums1.Length % 2 == 0)
        {
            double a = nums1[nums1.Length / 2 - 1];
            double b = nums1[nums1.Length / 2];
            double result = (a + b) / 2;
            return result;
        }
        return Convert.ToDouble(nums1[nums1.Length / 2]);

    }
    private int[] Concat(int[] x, int[] y)
    {
        int oldLen = x.Length;
        Array.Resize(ref x, x.Length + y.Length);
        Array.Copy(y, 0, x, oldLen, y.Length);
        return x;
    }
    private void SortArray(int[] array, int leftIndex, int rightIndex)
    {
        var i = leftIndex;
        var j = rightIndex;
        var pivot = array[leftIndex];
        while (i <= j)
        {
            while (array[i] < pivot)
            {
                i++;
            }

            while (array[j] > pivot)
            {
                j--;
            }
            if (i <= j)
            {
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }

        if (leftIndex < j)
            SortArray(array, leftIndex, j);
        if (i < rightIndex)
            SortArray(array, i, rightIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Объединение массивов требует времени `n + m`. Сортировка общего массива требует `(n + m)log(n + m)`. В задаче требования к скорости значительно выше: `log(n + m)`. Это значит что вы должны обойтись без объединения массивов и без сортировки. У вас даже нет времени чтобы просмотреть целиком два массива. Требуется совсем другое решение - двоичный поиск на паре массивов. Веселье только начинается.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Сортировку-то тут можно и слиянием сделать, за чистое n+m, хотя это, конечно, и не спасёт.

Comment: Мне всегда казалось что в таких задачах надо сначала сесть с бумажкой и придумать алгоритм.

Comment: @AlexeyTen мои знания в алгоритмах начинаются на ctrl+c, а заканчиваются ctrl+v, так что тут я примерно придумал план действий и попытался оптимизировать, взял знакомое слово "quick sort" и "реализовал" (см. первую часть предложения), ну а так как знаний нет совсем - пришел на стековерфлоу чтобы мне объяснили почему я дебс

Comment: @Aarnihauta В условии же явная подсказка  `O(log (m+n))`

Comment: @MBo мне это ни о чем не говорит, я не умею оценивать сложность алгоритмов

Comment: @Aarnihauta Так надо начать с хорошей книжки - Седжвик, Кормен

Comment: логарифм обычно говорит, что что-то делится и ищется в этой под-выборке, самый простой пример бинарный поиск в отсортированном массиве, мы делим пополам, потом ещё пополам, потом ещё пополам вот тут у нас и появляется логарифм. M+N говорит о том, что надо пробежаться по этим массивам не более чем какое-то константное количество раз, например алгоритм может пробежать по ним точно 3 раза для любого количества M и N

Comment: Еще бы знать, на каких исходных данных вы это тестировали.

Comment: @Komdosh Кажется, вы маленько загнули... M+N же под логарифмом

Comment: а это уже следующий шаг, как это всё скрестить, разделяй и властвуй

Comment: @Aarnihauta если вы не умеете оценивать сложность алгоритмов - что вы вообще делаете на leetcode? Копируя алгоритмы которых вы не понимаете, вы так ничему и не научитесь и продолжите ничего не понимать. Найдите хорошую книжку по алгоритмам (тут вам [Кормена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B:_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7) рекомендовали, отличная книга) и изучайте её.

Comment: @PavelMayorov у меня есть веские причины по которым я сразу приступаю к коду и только в самом серьёзном случае - к документации/книгам, но спасибо, я постараюсь почитать

Comment: @Aarnihauta что-то эти ваши веские причины очень похожи на "не хочу учиться". Но даже если они и правда веские - пересмотрите их и найдите время на изучение фундаментальных вещей. Кормен несложный (без шуток, это самая простая полезная книга по программированию которую я читал), а учиться программированию имея базовые знания намного проще.

Comment: @PavelMayorov понял, спасибо :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Решение

**NB** Индексация массивов с нуля. И порядковые статистики тоже нумеруются с нулевой.

Правда ли что `nums1[i]` - `k`-тая порядковая статистика в объединении массивов `nums1` и `nums2`?

Вычислим `j = k - i`. Если в объединённом массиве перед `nums1[i]` окажутся ровно `j` элементов из `nums2`, то ответ да. Для этого достаточно выполнения неравенства `nums2[j - 1] <= nums1[i] <= nums2[j]`. Если оно выполнено, то перед `nums1[i]` окажутся ровно `j` элементов из `nums2` и `i` элементов из `nums1`. А сам он окажется на месте с номером `j + i` (`= k`).

Определим метод `CheckOrderStatistic(nums1, nums2, i, k)` который возвращает `0` если `nums1[i]` - `k`-тая порядковая статистика. Также он возвращает `-1` если нарушается условие `nums1[i] <= nums2[j]` и `1` если нарушено условие `nums2[j - 1] <= nums1[i]`.

Пример:

`nums1 = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7]`, `nums2 = [2, 5]`, `k = 3`

> ```
> i                                          0  1  2  3  4  5
> CheckOrderStatistic(nums1, nums2, i, k)   -1 -1  0  1  1  1
> ```

Значения возрастают, можно применить двоичный поиск по `i`. Ищем ноль. Его может не быть. Это значит что на месте `k` находится элемент из массива `nums2`. В этом случае меняем местами `nums1` и `nums2` и выполняем ещё один двоичный поиск.

Сложность алгоритма `O(log(m) + log(n))`, где `m` и `n` длины массивов. В терминах О-большого `O(log(m) + log(n)) = O(log(m + n))`. Что и требовалось в условиях задачи.

### Сравнение

Это решение не покажется вам быстрее чем решение с сортировкой. Массивы длиной не более 1000 элементов. На таких размерах всё время уходит на загрузку программы в память. 160 ms и 39.2 MB - всё время и память потребляются рантаймом C#. Например память под массивы в задаче не превосходит восьми килобайт. Восемь килобайт на фоне 40 мегабайт. Со временем та же ситуация - на сортировку потребуются микросекунды на фоне миллисекунд. Не о чем говорить. Не даром в обсуждении решений на Литкоде всё сплошь сортировки и иногда слияния.

Чтобы измерить разницу между решениями нужны миллионы или миллиарды элементов. Тогда станет очевидно, что двоичный поиск быстрее. И это при условии что будет измеряться время исполнения одной функции решающей задачу, не всей программы.

### Код

Код проходит все тесты на Литкоде. По памяти и скорости где по-середине. Почему - я объяснил выше.

```
public class Solution {
    
    public double FindMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
        int n = nums1.Length + nums2.Length;
        int k1 = (n - 1) / 2;
        int k2 = (n - 1) - k1;
        double s1 = OrderStatistic(nums1, nums2, k1);
        double s2 = OrderStatistic(nums1, nums2, k2);
        return (s1 + s2) / 2;
    }

    // checks if nums1[i] is k-th order statistic in merged array
    private int CheckOrderStatistic(int[] nums1, int[] nums2, int i, int k) {
        int j = k - i;

        if (j < 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (nums2.Length < j) {
            return -1;
        }

        // nums2[j - 1] <= nums1[i]
        if (0 < j && nums2[j - 1] > nums1[i]) {
            return -1;
        }

        // nums1[i] <= nums2[j]
        if (j < nums2.Length && nums1[i] > nums2[j]) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private int Search(int[] nums1, int[] nums2, int k) {
        if (nums1.Length == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = nums1.Length - 1;
        int r_lo = CheckOrderStatistic(nums1, nums2, lo, k);
        if (r_lo == 0) {
            return lo;
        }
        if (r_lo > 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        int r_hi = CheckOrderStatistic(nums1, nums2, hi, k);
        if (r_hi == 0) {
            return hi;
        }
        if (r_hi < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        while(lo < hi - 1) {
            int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
            int r_mid = CheckOrderStatistic(nums1, nums2, mid, k);
            if (r_mid == 0) {
                return mid;
            }
            if (r_mid < 0) {
                lo = mid;
            } else {
                hi = mid;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private int OrderStatistic(int[] nums1, int[] nums2, int k) {
        int i1 = Search(nums1, nums2, k);
        if (i1 != -1) {
            return nums1[i1];
        }
        int i2 = Search(nums2, nums1, k);
        return nums2[i2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Для решения этой задачи нужен двойной двоичный (бинарный) поиск.

Обозначим исходные массивы A[1..n] и B[1..m]. Тогда нам надо найти такой число X, что количество элементов в A и B, которые ≤ X, равно (n+m)/2 (если это число не целое, то оба округления допустимы).

Попробуем поискать это число в первом массиве. Возьмём для начала X=A[i] и найдём сколько элементов в массиве B ≤ X, пусть это количество равно j = j(i). Так как массив B упорядочен, это число можно найти двоичным поиском. Но теперь количество элементов, которые ≤ X в обоих массивах, равно i + j.

Заметим, что получившаяся функция, f(i) = i + j(i), является монотонной. А значит, можно найти искомое (n+m)/2 среди её значений ещё одним двоичным поиском. И если оно нашлось - значит, A[i] и есть медиана.

Возможен также вариант, когда среди значений f(i) не нашлось (n+m)/2, а нашлось только что-то меньшее. Это значит, что искомая медиана лежит в массиве B. Обозначим максимальное i, для которого f(i) < (n+m)/2 (такое i должно было быть уже найдено неудачным двоичным поиском на прошлом шаге), тогда медиана должна быть B[(n+m)/2 - i]

Comment: а тут сложность будет не O(Log(n) * Log(M))?

Comment: @pavel именно такая и будет